# Preserve record when InLineEditing JQGrid gives error when adding or changing

Tags: jqgrid

I am using InLineEditing JQGrid and when adding or changing a record, if it fails, the record disappears. I need to preserve these lines for the user to correct the wrong information and try to save the record again.

Below my snippet code

```
jQuery("#" + p_gridName).jqGrid('inlineNav', '#p' + p_gridName, {
    edit : true, editicon : "ui-icon-pencil", 
    add : true, addicon : "ui-icon-plus",
    save : true, saveicon : "ui-icon-disk", savetitle : "Salvar",
    cancel : true, cancelicon : "ui-icon-cancel", canceltitle : "Cancelar",
    editParams :  {
        keys : false, oneditfunc : null, successfunc : function (response) {                    
            if (response != null && response.responseText != null) {                                                
                if (response.responseText.includes("OK")) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                    reloadDataGrid(p_gridName, p_contentName, p_filtroGrid);
                    atualizaInfoStatusNavegacao('edit', valorChave, p_primaryKey, p_contentName);
                    return true;
                } else {
                     alert(response.responseText);
                     return true;
                }
            }
        }, afterrestorefunc: function (rowid) {
                alert("after restore func");
                return rowid;
        }, restoreAfterError : false
    },
    addParams :  {
        useDefValues : true, addRowParams :  {
             successfunc : function (response) {
                 if (response.responseText.includes("OK")) {
                     alert(response.responseText);
                     reloadDataGrid(p_gridName, p_contentName, p_filtroGrid);
                     return true;
                 } else {
                     alert(response.responseText);
                     return true;
                 }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a option called **restoreAfterError** (see docs [here](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/user-guide/editing/#inline-methods)), which by default is true. Set it to false in order to get the desired behavior.

This is a option (parameter) in editRow or saveRow.

**EDIT**

Your code should return true or better array with first value true/false and message like this

```
        if (response != null && response.responseText != null) {                                                
            if (response.responseText.includes("OK")) {
                alert(response.responseText);
                reloadDataGrid(p_gridName, p_contentName, p_filtroGrid);
                atualizaInfoStatusNavegacao('edit', valorChave, p_primaryKey, p_contentName);
                return [true,''];
            } else {
                 return [false, response.responseText];
            }
        } else {
            return [false, 'no response from the server'];
        }
```

Comment: To save and change records in InLineEditing JQGrid, I use addParams and editParams. How can I call the "restoreAfterError" method within these structures?

Comment: I put the code snippet above for better understanding

Comment: I have point you to the docs, but it seems yo do not have read the docs for InLineEditiing navigator. As described  this parameter should be added in **editParams** and **addRowParams** (NOT addParams)

Comment: Tony, in the editParams section I inserted the "afterrestorefunc" and "restoreAfterError" properties after the "successfunc" parameter, but it didn't work. I updated the code snippet in the main question for better understanding. If I try to include a record that gives an error in the database for example, does JQGrid understand it as "afterrestorefunc",  "restoreAfterError" or "successfunc"?

Comment: If the error is from the server you should use successfunc as you do. If something is wrong in the server you should return false. As seen in your code you in both cases return true, which means that everything is ok, independent of error in the server. So IMHO you code should be look like in the edited my answer.  You can either return true/false or array as in my code

Comment: If I put the "return [false, response.responseText]", the line I am trying to edit is blocked and I lose all the information filled in the JQGrid columns. And if I'm trying to add a new record, the grid erases the row forcing me to fill it all in again

Comment: It depend which version of jqGrid is used. In Guriddo jqGrid this is working. You can visit our demo page. The example that cover your [case is here](http://www.guriddo.net/demo/guriddojs/edit_add_delete/inline_validation_serverside/index.html). The [demo is here](http://www.guriddo.net/demo/guriddojs/)

Comment: My JQGrid version is 4.5.4. I will migrate the version